# from a list of dictionaries drop dicts that share the same values for specific keys preferring the most recent

Tags: python

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
mylist = [{'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'pattern': 'striped', 'id': '10'},
          {'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '11'},
          {'color': 'red', 'size': 'large', 'pattern': 'striped', 'id': '12'},
          {'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '13'},
          {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'medium', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '14'}]
```

I want to remove dictionaries with the lowest values for the id key (leaving only the most recent) that have the same values for both the color and size keys. So in this case I want to end up with:

```
result = [{'color': 'red', 'size': 'large', 'pattern': 'striped', 'id': '12'},
          {'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '13'},
          {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'medium', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '14'}]
```

What is the best way to do this in python?

Comment: Does it have to be a list of dictionaries? Otherwise, a `structured array` might be an option. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html?highlight=structured%20array#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays

Comment: What should happen if there are 3 or more "duplicates"? Do you want to drop only the oldest `id`, or all but the newest one?

Comment: @tzaman I want to drop all but the newest one, I'll update the description.

Comment: @mapf - I am getting this list of dictionaries from a REST API, so my kick off point has to be a list of dictionaries, but that could be converted to a structured array if it makes sense to solve this problem

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

**Using sort and groupby**

```
sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: (d['color'], d['size'], int(d['id'])))
result = [list(v)[-1] for k, v in groupby(sorted_list, lambda d: (d['color'], d['size']))]
```

**Result**

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'id': '14', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'size': 'medium'},
 {'color': 'red', 'id': '12', 'pattern': 'striped', 'size': 'large'},
 {'color': 'red', 'id': '13', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'size': 'small'}]
```

**Explanation**

Sort elements so dictionaries with same color and size are consecutive and in ascending order by id

```
sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: (d['color'], d['size'], int(d['id'])))
```

Group sorted dictionaries by size and color

```
for k, v in groupby(sorted_list, lambda d: (d['color'], d['size']))
```

Dictionaries in each group are in ascending order by id.

Take last element of each group

```
result = [list(v)[-1] for k, v in groupby(...)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build an intermediate dict with tuples (color, size) as keys and your dicts as values, and update it when you encounter a new (color, size) combination, or an higher id for an existing one.

In the end, the output you want is just the list of its values.

```
mylist = [{'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'pattern': 'striped', 'id': '10'},
          {'color': 'red', 'size': 'large', 'pattern': 'striped', 'id': '11'},
          {'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '12'},
          {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'medium', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '13'}]

by_color_and_size = {}
for d in mylist:
    key = (d['color'], d['size'])
    if (key not in by_color_and_size 
        or int(d['id']) > int(by_color_and_size[key]['id'])):
        by_color_and_size[key] = d

out = list(by_color_and_size.values())

print(out)
# [{'color': 'red', 'size': 'small', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '12'},
#  {'color': 'red', 'size': 'large', 'pattern': 'striped', 'id': '11'},
#  {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'medium', 'pattern': 'spotted', 'id': '13'}]
```